# Rolling back edits counts as another edit

Tags: bug, editing

If you edit and then remove your edit manually then the two edits appear as a single edit under the heading "[Edit removed during grace period]". *However*, if you roll back your own edit then the grace period is not invoked and it counts as two edits.

I would have thought it would have been the other way round!

For example, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/10594/revisions).

My question is:

> Is this a bug?